# Cannot find a Resource with the Name / Key

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP App. The Styles works without a problem when I execute the app. But not in the Designer. Especially User Control can't be loaded. The Error message who is displayed is:

```
 Cannot find a Resource with the Name / Key [Name]
```

When I go to that User Control it mostly is displayed correctly.

I reference the style with:

```
                   Style="{StaticResource DeemphasizedBodyTextBlockStyle}"
```

I have a file for my Textstyles. In that file I have the style defined as followed:

```
<Style x:Key="DeemphasizedBodyTextBlockStyle"
       TargetType="TextBlock"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping"
            Value="NoWrap" />
    <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing"
            Value="75" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{StaticResource AppForegroundColorSecondary}" />
</Style>
```

And in the properties of the view project I have a Designer Resource file added (as page) with the following content:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Style/AppStyles.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Style/ColorsDark.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Style/ColorsLight.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Style/ControlStyles.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Style/TextStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The whole repo is available here: https://github.com/MoneyFox/MoneyFox